# PHP comparison is not workng with drop down menu

Tags: php, html

my drop down menu contains three option,

```
<select name="type" id="selBox">
    <option>---Select Type---</option>
    <option>Available</option>
    <option>Wanted</option>
</select>
```

When i validate the option in php, I use the below code

```
   if($type == '---Select Type--') { echo "<br> Select Type"; }
```

but it is not working ( === is also not working )

Comment: what is $type? You have not set value for option

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to set the values to your options:

```
<select name="type" id="selBox">
    <option value="">---Select Type---</option>
    <option value="Available">Available</option>
    <option value="Wanted">Wanted</option>
</select>
```

Then you can do a comparission like this:

```
if ($type == "") { echo "Your message"; }
```

Answer (score 4):

Heh:

You are comparing `---Select Type---` to `---Select Type--` which are not equal :p

Also better use `value` tag for options, and comparison goes simpler.

```
<select name="type" id="selBox">
    <option value="">---Select Type---</option>
    <option value="Available">Available</option>
    <option value="Wanted">Wanted</option>
</select>
```

PHP:

```
if($type == '') { echo "<br> Select Type"; }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think value is missing in `<option>` tag . May be you are trying to compare with value instead of option text.

Your Dropdown code will be :-

```
 <select name="type" id="selBox">
      <option value="">---Select Type---</option>
      <option value="Available">Available</option>
      <option value="Wanted">Wanted</option>
</select>
```

In PHP :-

```
if ($type == "") { echo "Your message"; }
```

**Edit :-**
As per comment if value missing then text in field become value:-
So you are missing one `-` while comparing :-

```
if($type == '---Select Type---') { echo "<br> Select Type"; }
```

Comment: If no value tag is set, then the text in the field will become the value.